# jQuery Tables with resizable columns and vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-resizable

Are there any jQuery plugins available on web which displays table with re sizable columns and horizontal scrollbar. Plugin like [colResizable](http://quocity.com/colresizable/) provides resizing only in a fixed area. Also dataTables.net do not provide such table options.

i would like to have a similar kind of table as shown in this [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/ezhmj8.png).

Thank you.

Comment: Not possible with jquery-datatables. There is a ColReorderWithResize plugin ->  http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize, but this does not work with datatables 1.10.x, and it works very poor with horizontal scrollbars (the headers and columns ends up being misaligned, see demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/rpw2Luzk/